# Link to other page/portlet in Liferay

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay

I just started with developing in Liferay (6.2).
We are making a portal for our customers and we are using JSF and primefaces.

The core functionality is working great. But now I am a little bit stuck.
We've got some pages where the customers can view there bought items and other stuff. Works also great.

But no, I want to go from the item (detail) to another page and take the `itemnumber` as parameter.

1. User goes to first page (all his bought items)
2. Clicks on detail -> the detail for this item are shown. Here I want to link to "messages".
3. Now the user is on the page "messages" and the filter is set to `itemnumber`.

The portlets are inserted only by us (not the customer - they have only "read-only" access)

Is this even the right approach to this problem? how could this be implemented?

Comment: Correct me if I didn't understand very well your question. You have 3 pages: 1- `Bought items` 2- `Item detail` and 3- `messages`. You want to redirect the user  from `Item detail` to `messages`by keeping the value of `itemnumber` ?

Comment: I have 2 Pages. `bought items` (which shows alos the details. but on the same page). And `messages`. Which shows all messages. but if i jump from the `items` page to the `messages` page, i want to init the filter with the id from the selected item.

Comment: Are `bought items` and `messages` in the same portlet ?

Comment: no. and thats the problem for me. different portlets - on different pages

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the requirement of your project, whether;
1. You want to stay on same page to display item details on pop_up or, 
2. You want to navigate to different page carrying request parameter(s) and based on that parameter(s) values, certain data is filtered and detail is shown.

If you follow 1st approach, you can place details link for each item in datatable or grid carrying unique `item_number`. Bind this link to bean's method (actionListener) and populate item details based on `item_number` extracted from action.

Or if you follow 2nd approach, you can simply bind detail page's link (static or dynamic from portlet's preferences) to hyperlink with `queryString` like `/details?item_number=x` where `x` is unique `item_number`. On details page (where your details portlet is dropped), extract that parameter from request and populate item details.

Both approaches are fine, as far as your requirement gets fulfilled. However, avoiding redirection would be good.

**Update:**

Add following link you `dataTable` in items portlet:

```
<h:outputLink target="_blank" value="/group/pages/message">
    Go to Messages
    <f:param name="item_number" value="#{item.itemNumber}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Where `/group/pages/message` is the URL of page and `item.itemNumber` is dynamic value of your `item` in `dataTable`.

Add following code to your constructor of message bean:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest =
    PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest));

int itemNumber = ParamUtil.getInteger(httpServletRequest, "item_number", 0);

if (itemNumber > 0) {
    // Filter messages here based on itemNumber
}
```

Comment: sorry. i think i did not make myself clear enough. The list and the detail is working fine. Also the messages page is there and working. But i've found no fine way to jump from the item-detail to the messages page and fill the filter with the item id.

Comment: Is your list data present in datatable?

Answer (score 1):

Since your facelets (JSF views) are in different portlets, you need to perform an `Inter Portlet Communication (IPC)`.

## **IPC using portlet session**

You can base your IPC on portlet session to pass your `itemnumber` to `messages` portlet. To perform this, in the **sender portlet**, get the session portlet as below

```
PortletSession portletSession = renderRequest.getPortletSession();
portletSession.setAttribute("key", value ,PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

And in the **receiver portlet**

```
PortletSession portletSession = renderRequest.getPortletSession();
String value = (String) portletSession.getAttribute("key ",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
// Do what ever you want...
```

In both portlets, add the following property in the `liferay-portlet.xml` file

```
private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
```

---

## IPC using public render parameters

Another way to pass your `itemnumber` to `messages` portlet is to use `public render parameters`. To do this, you need to define a public render parameter

```
<portlet-app ...>
    ...
    <public-render-parameter>
        <identifier>identifier</identifier>
        <qname xmlns:x="http://namespace.com">x:identifier</qname>
    </public-render-parameter>
    ...
</portlet-app>
```

And declare it in **both** portlets as below

```
<portlet>
    ...
    <supported-public-render-parameter>identifier</supported-public-render-parameter>
    ...
<portlet>
```

You can then **send** the `itemnumber` as below

```
actionReponse.setRenderParameter("identifier", value);
```

And **retrieve** it

```
renderRequest.getParameter("identifier");
// Do what ever you want...
```

---

## IPC using event

The last way to pass your `itemnumber` is by using `event`. Since you are using `JSF` as Portlet framework, eventing between portlets is quite different. You must follow these steps:

**1. Define your event**

Define an event in the `portlet.xml` file

```
<event-definition xmlns:event="http://www.namespace.com">
     <qname>identifier</qname>
     <value-type>java.lang.String</value-type>
</event-definition>
```

**2. Create an event bridge handler**

Create an class that implements `BridgeEventHandler` as below

```
public class CustomBridgeEventHandler implements BridgeEventHandler {


        @Override
        public EventNavigationResult handleEvent(FacesContext facesContext, Event event) {

            EventNavigationResult eventNavigationResult = null;

            // Processing the event will be written here...

            return eventNavigationResult;
        }
    }
```

**3. Sender portlet**
In the sender portlet, you need to declare both the event and the bridge handler in the `portlet.xml` file.

**Event**

```
<portlet>
    ...
    <supported-publishing-event xmlns:event="http://www.namespace.com">
        <qname>identifier</qname>
    </supported-publishing-event>
    ...
</portlet>
```

**Bridge**

```
<portlet>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <name>javax.portlet.faces.bridgeEventHandler</name>
        <value>com.roufid.tutorials.bridge.CustomBridgeEventHandler</value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</portlet>
```

**Fire the event**

```
public void yourMethod() {
    // Getting the faces context.
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    // Getting the portlet action response.
    ActionResponse actionReponse = (ActionResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    // Firing the event
    QName qName = new QName("http://www.namespace.com ", "identifier");
    actionReponse.setEvent(qName, dataYouWantToSend);
}
```

**4. Receiver portlet**
In the receiver portlet, you need to declare both the event and the bridge handler in the `portlet.xml` file.

**Event**

```
<portlet>
    ...
    <supported-publishing-event xmlns:event="http://www.namespace.com">
        <qname>identifier</qname>
    </supported-publishing-event>
    ...
</portlet>
```

**Bridge**

```
<portlet>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <name>javax.portlet.faces.bridgeEventHandler</name>
        <value>com.roufid.tutorials.bridge.CustomBridgeEventHandler</value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</portlet>
```

**Process the event in the bridge handler**

```
public class CustomBridgeEventHandler implements BridgeEventHandler {

    @Override
    public EventNavigationResult handleEvent(FacesContext facesContext, Event event) {

        EventNavigationResult eventNavigationResult = null;

        String eventQName = event.getQName().toString();

        // Processing the defined event.
        if (eventQName.equals("{http://www.namespace.com}identifier")) {

            // Getting the event value.
            String value = (String) event.getValue();

            // Do what ever you want here...
    }

        return eventNavigationResult;
    }
}
```

---

In all cases, since your portlets are in different wars, you need to add this property in `portlet-ext.properties` file to allow the IPC between portlets located in different Liferay pages

```
 portlet.public.render.parameter.distribution=layout-set
```

## More informations and examples

- [IPC using session](http://roufid.com/liferay-ipc-using-portlet-session/) | [example](https://github.com/RadouaneRoufid/tutorials/tree/master/IPCSession)
- [IPC using public render parameters](http://roufid.com/liferay-portlet-communication-using-public-render-parameter/) | [example](https://github.com/RadouaneRoufid/tutorials/tree/master/IPC-Public-Render-Parameter)
- [IPC using event](http://roufid.com/liferay-jsf-portlet-communication/) | [example](https://github.com/RadouaneRoufid/tutorials/tree/master/IPC-JSF-Event)